# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (jQuery ALREADY defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane, and I'm getting jQuery is not defined.

We all know the universal answer to this: load jQuery first, however, i'm loading it before, and i'm intializing jScrollPane on $(document).ready() (I'm using jquery, how can it not be there?)

Here's my markup:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" url="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" url="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Jscrollpane so we can style scroll bar cross-browser -->
    <!-- styles needed by jScrollPane -->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Setting up the dropdown */
    var dropdown = new DropdownMenu();
    dropdown.run();

    /* Setting scrollbar */
    $('#dropdown-menu .content').jScrollPane();
});
```

What may be happening? All I can find around the web is telling me to initialize jquery first, but it is initialized.

Comment: Are you sure http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js loaded correctly? How did you *check* that jQuery was actually defined?

Comment: try using attribute `src` instead of `url`<< ??? Using your network tab should have pointed you to this issue

Comment: `We all know the universal answer to this: load jQuery first, however, i'm loading it before` - nope. You're obviously not. Look at @Irvin wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `url` attribute instead of `src` in your script tag reference? I don't think it's a valid syntax.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not really sure where did the url attribute came from. I probably got it from somewhere or wrote it while half-asleep. Never really looked into it because jQuery was working. Your answer made me realize that jQuery was defined twice. In my head with url and at the end of by body with the right src tag.

Everything working now, thanks.